# Mongoose auto-increment

Tags: mongoose, auto-increment

I would like to create auto increment ID with Mongoose for MongoDB. I was already looking for some examples, but there aren't anything useful other the MongoDB's documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Use mongoose-sequence, For eg: In the below model, it increments order number by one when a new document is inserted.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);

const orderSchema = new Schema({
   _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   orderId: {
     type: Number
   }
   ...
});

orderSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {inc_field: 'orderId'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

There is an important thing that needs to be understood. If you add **required: true** in the schema, the **operation breaks**.

In your route file, you can create a mongoose order object and call save.

```
...
const order = new Order(body);
order.save()
     .then(doc => {
       res.json(doc);
       res.end();
     });
```

Comment: mongoose-sequence does not work with mongo 7

Answer (score 5):

On npm we have [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) and [mongoose-sequence](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence) packages to achieve this functionality very easily.

Comment: `mongoose-sequence` is the way to go from what I saw - thank you. `mongoose-auto-increment` uses deprecated functions and wasn't updated since 2016 (abandoned?) - let's blame https://github.com/chevex.